# mysql - how to select one value to only one row then multiple others to all other rows

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables (studentstbl and subjectstbl). They both have 'Year' column. How can I select only one name from studentstbl to only one row then the others have all the subjects that is included from whatever the 'Year' the subjects and the student are. Like this:

```
Student_Name     Subjects
Nora             Algebra
                 Physics
                 Psycho
```

But I always end up getting this using inner join:

```
Student_Name     Subjects
Nora             Algebra
Nora             Physics
Nora             Psycho
```

I used this code

```
select studentstbl.LastName, subjectstbl.*
from studentstbl tb1 
inner join subjectstbl tb2 
on tb1.Year = tb2.Year
```

Comment: what is common field for student and subject table ?

Comment: If you'll just read clearly my question, it's 'Year'.

Comment: If you will just write you question clearly and correctly , then he won't have to ask

Comment: I added an example output that I need. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include both tables with all relevant columns containing dummy data and the expected format of the result along with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column name of the second table if it has the same columnName with the other table, you need to supply an ALIAS on it,

```
SELECT  studentstbl.name, subjectstbl.*
FROM    studentstbl tb1
INNER JOIN subjectstbl tb2
ON tb1.year = tb2.year where year='2016'
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me multiple LastNames. Is it possible to have only one?

Comment: @eilraK now check it with your common year.

Comment: I still get multiple Last Names

Comment: @eilraK then there are other students which have same year.